# AWS S3: Unable to load credentials into profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

When I access S3 from CLI, it returns the buckets.

aws s3 ls druid-s3-bucket
PRE pccpdevint/
PRE test-druid/
2022-03-15 21:41:36          4 tes

But from the SDK, it fails with the error

```
Unable to load credentials into profile [druidbotint]: AWS Access Key ID is not specified., com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@2ff8d560: Failed to connect to service endpoint: , com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider@3cad42b9: Failed to connect to service endpoint: ]
    at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:136) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.37.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.getCredentialsFromContext(AmazonHttpClient.java:1266) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.37.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.runBeforeRequestHandlers(AmazonHttpClient.java:842) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.37.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:792) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.37.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:779) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.37.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:753) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.37.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:713) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.37.jar:?]
```

I have a custom role and I have an external process to look up credentials
Here is the aws/credential file

```
[default]

source_profile = druidbotint
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::1233:role/worker-role
role_session_name = druidbotsession

[druidbotint]
credential_process = awsconnect -u druid_s -a 1233 -r custom_role -p conf
```

Here is the aws/config file

```
[profile conf]
region = us-west-2
```

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: Looking briefly at [Sourcing credentials with an external process - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-sourcing-external.html), I wonder whether you should provide the **absolute path** for `awsconnect`? Have you ever has `awsconnect` working successfully?

Comment: Yes, it has worked. If I give admin access, it works. Something like `credential_process = awsconnect -u druid_s -a 1233 -r admin -p conf`. The problem happens when I have to assume role

Comment: Did you try the absolute path? eg `credential_process = /usr/bin/awsconnect ...`?

Comment: We did not. but maybe worth a try